# how to do condition based don't repeat yourself (dry) principle in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, dry

[image: code output]

way to use component:

```
  import React from "react";
  import MyAvatars from "../../components/MyAvatar/MyAvatars";

  const About = () => {
   return (
  
    <MyAvatars
      topType={[true, 1000]}
      accessoriesType={[true, 1200]}
      facialHairType={["blank"]}
    />
   );
 };

 export default About;
```

This is my code.
I am currently working on this.

**Code:**

```
  import React from "react";
  import Avatar from "avataaars";
  import { Top, Accessories, FacialHair } from "./avatarThings";

  const MyAvatar = ({ topType, facialHairType }) => {
  
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = React.useState({
      avatarStyle: "Circle",
      topType: "ShortHairDreads01",
      accessoriesType: "Blank",
      facialHairType: "Blank",
});


const topFunc = () =>{
    if (topType.length === 2) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setAvatar((prev) => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            topType:  Top[Math.floor(Math.random() * Top.length)],
          };
        });
      }, topType[1]); //this is time
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
    setAvatar((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        topType: topType[0],
      };
    });
}

const FacialHairFunc = () =>{
      if (facialHairType.length === 2) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setAvatar((prev) => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            facialHairType: FacialHair[Math.floor(Math.random() * FacialHair.length)],
          };
        });
      }, facialHairType[1]);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
    setAvatar((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        facialHairType: facialHairType[0],
      };
    });
}

React.useEffect(() => {

  if (topType) {
    topFunc()
  }
  if (facialHairType) {
    FacialHairFunc()
  }

}, [])


return (
  <Avatar
    avatarStyle="Circle"
    topType={avatar.topType}
    accessoriesType={avatar.accessoriesType}
    hairColor={avatar.hairColor}
    facialHairType={avatar.facialHairType}
  />

 );
};

export default MyAvatar;
```

I am new to programming.
I am currently creating a useful **open-source NPM Package**.

This is the code for it.
Repeat the same code over and over again.

I wish I could modify this code more easily than this, but I could not.
It's very easy for people to admire you.
And I'll learn new things with the code you write for this.

I would be very glad if you help.

Please help and let me know your **contribution** as well.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a bit of coupling between the functions to effectively compute a random attribute, and the aspect of updating the avatar state.

I suggest converting each "attribute" function that selects a random attribute and updates the state into a single React hook that takes an array of attributes and the interval, and returns the random attributes, and simply pass each randomly selected attribute directly to the `Avatar` component. There's not a compelling reason to have the intermediate `avatar` state in your component.

Example:

```
const getRandomAttribute = arr => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

const useRandomAttribute = (attributes = [], valueArr = []) => {
  const [attribute, setAttribute] = useState(() => {
    if (valueArr[0]) {
      return getRandomAttribute(attributes);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let timerId;
    if (valueArr[0] && valueArr[1] > 0) {
      timerId = setInterval(() => {
        const attribute = getRandomAttribute(attributes);
        setAttribute(attribute);
      }, valueArr[1]);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
  }, [attributes, valueArr]);

  return attribute;
};
```

App

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "avataaars";
import { Top, Accessories, FacialHair, ..... } from "./avatarThings";

const MyAvatar = ({ topType, facialHairType, accessoriesType, hairType }) => {
  const accessory = useRandomAttribute(Accessories, accessoriesType);
  const face = useRandomAttribute(FacialHair, facialHairType);
  const hair = useRandomAttribute(Hair, hairType);
  const top = useRandomAttribute(Top, topType);

  return (
    <Avatar
      avatarStyle="Circle"
      topType={top || "ShortHairDreads01"}
      accessoriesType={accessory || "Blank"}
      hairColor={hair || "BrownDark"}
      facialHairType={face || "Blank"}
      clotheType="Hoodie"
      clotheColor="Red"
      eyeType="Wink"
      eyebrowType="Default"
      mouthType="Smile"
      skinColor="Brown"
    />
  );
};
```

You can tune the code from here for the interval timing, other default/fallback values, etc.

[image: Edit how-to-do-condition-based-dont-repeat-yourself-dry-principle-in-react-js]

Comment: Sir, I tried to use your code, but the error persists as it continues to run.

This should only work when there are two values ​​in the component, otherwise only the value given in the component should be returned.

However I wonder if this can be written so easily.
And I have edited the question a bit and I think you will understand if you see this. @drew-reese

Comment: @JacksonKasi Perhaps I've misunderstood your expectation.... there's a `setInterval` involved, so why *wouldn't* it continue to run? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live? TBH I had to make some guesses as to the prop values being passed to the component and that the code would get you "close enough" to what you were after. We can continue refining though.

Comment: I have added a small change to this.

The codesanbox "Array .length" error is coming up.

You run this code on your land and you will get no error.

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-oskar-834s6l?file=/src/MyAvatars.js

Comment: @JacksonKasi Ok, you had several issues with your code. After played around a bit more I've resolved togging the intervals for avatar parts on the boolean and delay values. Updated the codesandbox and answer here.

Comment: Damn I'm so embarrassed to think I did not notice such a small thing, while at the same time wondering at your code thinking.

I am so glad you helped me.
Thank you so much :)

A little help, please tell me if there is any way to write code very neatly and simply like you, if you have any suggestions :)

Comment: @JacksonKasi Lots of practice and repetition. Lots of reading and reviewing other people's code. Lots of reading succinct, working code and dissecting it to *really* understand how it works. I think a lot comes with experience and time, just have to keep at it. I've sometimes gone back only a month or so and saw some code I wrote and thought to myself, "WTF was I thinking then?! Why did I do it that way?" Don't stop learning new things and tricks.

Comment: No word to praise yourself.
Today I am very happy to have a good friend and good advice almost.

Comment: @JacksonKasi Also, nothing to be embarrassed about, we all started at the beginning and didn't know anything.

Answer (score 1):

Do you can create just a function parsing the required args:

```js
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "avataaars";
import { Top, Accessories, FacialHair } from "./avatarThings";

const MyAvatar = ({ topType, facialHairType }) => {

const [avatar, setAvatar] = React.useState({
    avatarStyle: "Circle",
    topType: "ShortHairDreads01",
    accessoriesType: "Blank",
    facialHairType: "Blank",
});

const typeFunction = (type, AvatarComponent) =>{
    if (type.length === 2) {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setAvatar((prev) => {
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    type: AvatarComponent[Math.floor(Math.random() * AvatarComponent.length)],
                };
            });
        }, type[1]);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
    setAvatar((prev) => {
        return {
            ...prev,
            type: type[0],
        };
    });
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (topType) {
        typeFunction(type, Top)
    }
    if (facialHairType) {
        typeFunction(facialHairType, FacialHair)
    }
}, [])


return (
        <Avatar
            avatarStyle="Circle"
            topType={avatar.topType}
            accessoriesType={avatar.accessoriesType}
            hairColor={avatar.hairColor}
            facialHairType={avatar.facialHairType}
        />
    );
};

export default MyAvatar;
```

Comment: Your code has been very helpful to me.
I am so glad you helped me.
Thank you so much :)